# NRPE installation issues "Starting nrpe in daemon mode ... /usr/sbin/nrpe: error while loading"

Tags: centos, nagios, rpm

I'm trying to install the nrpe package for OP5 on Centos. I think something is corrupt since I get following when trying to start the nrpe service: service nrpe start

> Starting nrpe in daemon mode ... /usr/sbin/nrpe: error while loading
>   shared libraries: libssl.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory failed!

So, I did try to remove the package because I was thinking about making a fresh install, but it seemed not to be installed:

> rpm -e nrpe-2.13-nagios_plugins-1.4.15-CentOS_6-2.13.1_x86_64.rpm

which gave me:

> error: package
>   nrpe-2.13-nagios_plugins-1.4.15-CentOS_6-2.13.1_x86_64.rpm is not
>   installed

So I figured I should install it:

> pm -i --test
>   nrpe-2.13-nagios_plugins-1.4.15-CentOS_6-2.13.1_x86_64.rpm

which says it's already installed:

```
[root@smicloud ~]# rpm -i --test nrpe-2.13-nagios_plugins-1.4.15-CentOS_6-2.13.1_x86_64.rpm 
    package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 is already installed
    file /usr/sbin/nrpe from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_apt from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_by_ssh from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_cluster from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_dhcp from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_disk from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_dummy from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_http from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_icmp from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_ide_smart from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_load from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_mrtg from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_mrtgtraf from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_mysql from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_mysql_query from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_nagios from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_nt from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_ntp from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_ntp_peer from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_ntp_time from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_nwstat from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_overcr from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_pgsql from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_ping from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_procs from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_real from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_smtp from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_ssh from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_swap from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_tcp from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_time from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_ups from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/check_users from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/negate from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/urlize from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /opt/plugins/utils.pm from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
    file /usr/sbin/libexec/check_nrpe from install of nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nrpe_nagiosplugins-2.13.1-release.x86_64
```

What I did before I realise I need a specific nrpe package for OP5 was to try to install nrpe using yum. But then I removed it, seems to have worked fine.

Then accidantly I tried to install an nrpe package for Centos 5.x, which I tried to remove. I think I got the same kind of symptoms as for above even here, both for installing and removing.

How can I fix this? Or where can I start looking in order to find more information that can help me solving this.

I am a newbie, perhaps this is simple stuff...?

Comment: Reason for -1 so I can make it better next time please?

Comment: This is a CentOS question, not a nagios question.

Comment: Check my own answer. Honestly don't know how to categorize it...

Answer (score 0):

The problems was that there were remaining plugins for Nagios version of NRPE still installed. Once removed it worked like a charm installing the NRPE for OP5.